# when I run a py file using the pgzrun command in command prompt, it doesn't allow me to

Tags: python

when I run a py file using the pgzrun (It's a python command) command in command prompt, it doesn't allow me to run my code and it says: *'pgzrun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

Comment: there is not enough information in this question to answer it? First is Pygame Zero installed? What is the exact command you are running? What is in the file you are trying to run? what is the stacktrace of the error?